# ##[error]Error: The process '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5_18_2/bin/msbuild' failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-app-center

I'm a bit of a newbie with Xamarin and I have an issue when building to app center, I hope someone can give me some pointers,

My app builds fine on iOS but it's coming up with this error for Android, could anyone please point me in the right direction?

```
[error]Error: The process '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5_18_2/bin/msbuild' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: try to remove the reference to mscorlib and  go into the build settings - on App Center - and change the Mono version to the latest

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT how to do that (remove reference to mscorlib)?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am having a similar issue ```##[error]Error: The process '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6_4_0/bin/msbuild```

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT just changing to the latest mono version(i.e. 10.0 -> 10.1) fixed it for me.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT  my is alreay latest and facing same issue

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT can you please provide more detalies about the steps I need to do? I am really new to Xamarin and I am confused about where should I do what you said

Answer (score 3):

This error shows that there was an issue building your application in *App Center*. *App Center* builds your application just like you do when you *build* your application in Visual Studio.

Just above the red `##[error]Error: The process '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6_12_7/bin/msbuild' failed with exit code 1` it should show you more details on why your application failed to build.

This example shows what the output could look like. A summary of the errors and warnings and the specific error details shown above the summary.

In this case there were 2 errors. Some namespaces used in these two files could not be found.

[image]

So when there is an issue with your in *App Center* have a look at the error detail to find your issue

Comment: Very good answer. Thanks a lot! it actually helped me solve a couple of other issues

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.
In case you are able to run a build your Xamarin Android project successfully from Visual Studio, your problem might be coming from the App Center build config.
More specifically the SDK Version. To change the SDK version I invite you to do the following on your App Center Android project:

1. Go to Build
2. Select your build
3. Go to build configuration (it's the wrench icon on the top right)
4. then you'll have a drop-down to select the SDK version (I recommend you to select the latest stable one)

I hope it helped, don't hesitate to ask me questions in the comment if you are lost

Comment: HI @Bryce,
I Upgraded my project from SDK 12.0 to 13.0. After that I'm getting below error if I build in Release mode.
"R8 : Validation error : A type variable is not in scope."
"The process '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6_12_24/bin/msbuild' failed with exit code 1"

The error is coming from R8. Below is the configuration from my Manifest file:

<AndroidDexTool>d8</AndroidDexTool>
<AndroidLinkTool>r8</AndroidLinkTool>
<AndroidLinkMode>Full</AndroidLinkMode>

If I remove the R8, the app builds successfully, But I don't want to go without R8.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the build settings -> on AppCenter-> and change the Mono version to the latest.

Comment: I am really new to Xamarin and I am not sure where should I change the Mono version?

Comment: @OvidiuUşvat On AppCenter, in your build configuration you'll be able to change the Mono version 